# ReactJS asynchronous global API request method, how to handle response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am attempting to build a global API request function considering the repetitiveness of it. The problem I have is despite the responseBody object not being null when the function ends, the response seems to be null?

I can only assume this is in part due to the object being returned before it is updated.

Here is the function:

export function restRequest(url, method, content, body) {

```
fetch(API_BASE_URL + url, {
    method: method,
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': content,
        'Access-Control-Request-Method': method,
        // 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    }),
    body: body
}).then(
    function (response) {

        response.json().then((data) => {
            let json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

            let responseBody = {
                code: response.status,
                body: json
            };

            //at this point the responseBody is not null

            return responseBody;
        });
    }
)
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
```

However if I make a call:

```
    let response = restRequest('/app/rest/request', 'GET', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', null);
```

response is always null.

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's asynchronous, so any call of `restRequest` will not immediately return the `responseBody` = you need to properly chain the promises, and call `.then` on the `restRequest` call. Return the `fetch` call from the `restRequest` function, and avoid the promise-callback antipattern by returning `response.json()` immediately, rather than nesting a `.then` inside it:

```
export const restRequest = (url, method, content, body) => (
  fetch(API_BASE_URL + url, {
    method: method,
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': content,
      'Access-Control-Request-Method': method,
      // 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    }),
    body
  })
  .then(response => Promise.all([response.status, response.json()])
  .then(([code, body]) => ({ code, body }))
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  })
);
```

then do

```
restRequest('/app/rest/request', 'GET', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', null)
  .then(response => {
    // do stuff with response. (if there was an error, response will be undefined)
  });
```

Comment: In terms of returning both the response status and the body, how would you handle that? Thanks though this is a lot clearer..

Comment: Ah, good point - use `Promise.all` to return both the `status` and the body